# Import additional nodes to existing network in Cytoscape, preserving layout

Tags: cytoscape

I'm needing to add a new set of nodes to an existing network and layout. This refers to the desktop client, but for illustration if you think of the wine and cheese demo (http://www.wineandcheesemap.com/) and I'd be adding "bread" nodes that need to have new edges to the cheeses similarly to the wines.

Even after reviewing documentation I'm struggling to understand whether this is possible in bulk, without having to reload from scratch and thus destroying the layout.

I've found the merge function, but even so, that one destroys the layout too. Automatic layouts don't work for me as they're not consistent and have many overlaps in my use case.

I'd be grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex stated, this will necessarily be difficult.  However, you can use the copyCatLayout app to save your initial layout and restore it after a merge.  The location of the new "bread" nodes will, obviously, be somewhat random and will probably need to be manually repositioned...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for me to imagine how to introduce a lot of new nodes and edges while preserving the original layout precisely. The original layout was based on the original nodes and edges... and that is what is necessarily changing.  You could manually add a few nodes into a layout, of course. But once you are talking about dozens or more, then I think automatic layouts are the way to go.

There are a few things you can do to greatly improve the final output of automatic layouts:

1. Layout Tools: Here you can use scale to create space evenly between all nodes
2. Layout Settings: Here you can tune the parameters of any of the open source layout algorithms to adjust how crowded or sparse your nodes end up
3. Try the yFiles layouts, which appear to have an extract step to minimize overlaps

Comment: Thank you. There's some useful learning in your answer, appreciated.